# Where using SequelizeJS and MySQL

Tags: sequelize.js

I'd like to create a custom "where" using sequelizejs but I don't know how to proceed...

I'd like to get all `events` from my database where `end` is after the current `NOW()` date...

My code :

```
Event.findAll({where: {state: 1}, order: 'start asc'});
```

Is that possible to put `where: {end: '< NOW()'}` in the `where` object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like the following will do it for you:

```
Event.findAll({
  where: {
    state: 1,
    end: {
      $lt: Sequelize.fn('NOW')
    }
  }
});
```

That generates the query: `SELECT id, state, end, sq_created_at, sq_updated_at FROM event AS event WHERE event.state = 1 AND event.end < NOW();`

I have uploaded a script demo'ing this example [here](https://github.com/cfogelberg/sequelize-playground/tree/master/tests/13-where-example). The Sequelize JS documentation on operators is [here](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/querying/#operators).